# Program crashes when test value approaches _int32 maximum or negative, but works fine going well above _int16... What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c, max, return-value, negative-number

I am currently trying to create the following function that return 1 when:

- A. Any bit of x equals 1.
- B. Any bit of x equals 0.
- C. Any bit in the least significant byte of x equals 1.
- D. Any bit in the least significant byte of x equals 0.

I'm not allowed to use any equality or inequality tests, conditionals, etc.

ONLY booleans (&&, ||, &, |, !, ~)

I wrote this up and it seemed to work okay, that is until I tried to test it for special cases, such as all 1's (negatives and maximum int values). I seem to find that my program crashes when there is a value in the most significant byte of the test_value. My program runs properly and does all the functions, but when it crashes, instead of returning 0, it returns me a random integer. When this happens, I try to track my program with the debugger, and each step of my `int main()` seems to have no issues until the last line, `return 0;` Other than that I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong.

I don't really like posting a question without any more background information, but I'm not sure at all what I am doing incorrectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void displayBinary(int test)
{
        char bistr[20];
        itoa(test,bistr,2);
        printf("%s",bistr);
}

int part_A(int test)
{
    return !!test;
}

int part_B(int test)
{
    int not_test = ~test;
    return !!(not_test);
}

int part_C(int test)
{
    int mask = test & 0xFF;
    return !!mask;
}


int part_D(int test)
{
    int num_shift = (sizeof(test)-1)*8;
    int shifted = test >> num_shift;
    shifted = ~shifted;
    return !!shifted;
}

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    //int test_value = rand();
    //int test_value = ~0;   //0 = all 0, ~0= all 1
    int test_value = 2147483647;    //CRASHES FOR THIS AS WELL AS FOR ~0 AND -1
    printf("Number is: %d \n", test_value);
    printf("Size is: %d bytes\n",sizeof(test_value));
    printf("Hex representation is: %.8x \n", test_value);
    printf("Binary representation is: ");
    displayBinary(test_value);
    printf("\n");
    part_A(test_value) && printf("There is a bit equal to 1. \n");
    (!part_A(test_value)) && printf("There are no bits equal to 1. \n");
    part_B(test_value) && printf("There is a bit equal to 0. \n");
    (!part_B(test_value)) && printf("There are no bits equal to 0. \n");
    part_C(test_value) && printf("There is a bit equal to 1 in LSB. \n");
    (!part_C(test_value)) && printf("There are no bits equal to 1 in LSB. \n");
    part_D(test_value) && printf("There is a bit equal to 0 in MSB. \n");
    (!part_D(test_value)) && printf("There are no bits equal to 0 in MSB. \n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output when crashing:

```
Number is: 2147483647
Size is: 4 bytes
Hex representation is: 7fffffff
Binary representation is: 1111111111111111111111111111111
There is a bit equal to 1.
There is a bit equal to 0.
There is a bit equal to 1 in LSB.
There is a bit equal to 0 in MSB.

Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)      execution time : 1.358s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: FWIW, using && instead of "if" might be an idiom in Perl, but it certainly isn't in C.

Comment: Sorry, I've never done Perl. 

My professor taught us that when we have two statements connected by &&, it'll check whether the first statement is true and if so, check the next statement/execute the next statement.

if the first statement evaluates to false, it skips the second.

Is what I'm doing not recommended? because I saw a few examples online where people did this so I assumed it was okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void displayBinary(int test)
{
        char bistr[20];
```

For big integers, the length of the binary form (like `1111111111111111111111111111111` in your example) is over the size of `bistr`.

Comment: SHOOT. Thank you so much. Good to know it was more on the side of careless mistake than improper technique.

Answer (score 0):

The following code smashes your stack:

```
    char bistr[20];
    itoa(test,bistr,2);
    printf("%s",bistr);
```

`test` can be a 32 bits number, so at the very least you'll need 33 characters to always be able to represent it. Now, you'll need more if `int` is 64 bits, so safer is to use something like `sizeof(int) * 8 + 1` to determine array size:

```
    char bistr[sizeof(int) * 8 + 1];
    itoa(test,bistr,2);
    printf("%s",bistr);
```

Comment: THank you!!! That is actually a great piece of advice, I'll definitely use it next time! makes more sense too, working across more machines, thanks!